# Entity Framework 6: How do I reset a database using code first migrations and an FTP deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ftp, entity-framework-migrations

I deploy to a staging server that I don't have control over and have only been given FTP access.  I've successfully used EF6 Code Migrations to create and seed the database on the staging server using the [method described here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1993064.aspx?MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion).

I would like to basically do the equivalent of the following, but in code, when I deploy via FTP:

```
Update-database -TargetMigration:0

Update-database
```

**My goal:** I have new seed data to replace the existing data.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As usual I always figure it out moments after posting a question. (I promise I was looking for a long time before finally posting)

I did not realize you could pass a ConnectionString argument to Update-Database. So basically this was all I needed in the end:

```
Update-database -TargetMigration:0 -ConnectionString "MY_STAGING_CONNECTION_STRING" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
```

And then on my next deploy it automatically migrated back to the latest version.